# Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException even the interface seems to be registered

Tags: c#, exception, dependency-injection, autofac

I try to implement a WPF application using dependency injection and the MVVM pattern using the frameworks "CommunityFramework.MVVM" and "Autofac".

What I have so far is the the following(shows only the required parts):

- in Main Project.
  Namespace: .UI.WPF

```
public class App : Application
{
    private IContainer _container;

    public App()
    {
        _builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Installer));
        string fullPath = assembly!.Location;
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)!;

        _builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);

        var assemblyPath = Path.Combine(dir, "ViewModel.dll");
        Debug.Assert(File.Exists(assemblyPath));
        assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
        _builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);

         assemblyPath = Path.Combine(dir, "Model.dll");
         Debug.Assert(File.Exists(assemblyPath));
         assembly = Assembly.LoadFile(assemblyPath);
         builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);

         _container = _builder.Build();
    }
    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnStartup(e);

        var start = _container?.Resolve<IShell<IMainWindow>>();
        // HERE the Exception occcures !!!
        var workSpace = _container?.Resolve<IMainWindowViewModel>();

        ....
    }
}

public interface IShell<T> where T:class
{
    // some defines here
}

public class Shell : IShell<IMainWindow>
{
    public Shell()
    {
        // some initialization here
    }
}
public class Installer : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Shell
        object ret = builder.RegisterType<Shell>()
            .As<IShell<IMainWindow>>()
            .SingleInstance();

        // Messanger
        builder.Register(_ => MessageListener.Listen().Messenger)
            .As<IMessenger>()
            .SingleInstance();
    }
}
```

- in Project ViewModel:
  Namespace: .ViewModel

```
public class Installer : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // MainWindowViewModel
        builder.RegisterType<MainWindowViewModel>()
            .As<IMainWindowViewModel>()
        .    SingleInstance();
    }
}

public interface IMainWindowViewModel
{
    // some entries here
}

public class MainWindowViewModel : ObservableRecipient, IMainWindowViewModel
{
    private IMessenger _messenger;
    private IMyProjectData_data;

    public MainWindowViewModel(IMyProjectDatadata, IMessenger messenger)
        : base(messenger)
    {
        _data = data;
        _messenger = messenger;
    }
}
```

- in Project Model:
  Namespace: .Models

```
public class Installer : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        // Foto-Renamer Data
        builder.RegisterType<MyProjectData>()
            .As<IMyProjectData>()
            .SingleInstance();

        // Setings
        builder.RegisterType<Settings>()
            .As<ISettings>().
            SingleInstance();
    }
}

public interface IMyProjectData
{
    // some entries here
}

public partial class MyProjectData : ObservableObject, IMyProjectData
{
    private ISettings _settings;

    public MyProjectData(ISettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        // more initialization here
    }
}

public interface ISettings
{
    // some entries here
}

public class Settings : ISettings
{
    private IShell<IWindow> _shell;

    public Settings(IShell<IMainWindow> shell)
    {
        _shell = shell;
        //more initializations here
    }
}
```

At the marked Point i get the following exeption:

## EDIT:

### Exception:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: "An exception was thrown while activating MyProject.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel."

### Stack trace:

> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<Execute>b__0() at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.CreateSharedInstance(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
> at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.CreateSharedInstance(Guid primaryId, Nullable`1 qualifyingId, Func`1 creator)
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.SharingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.CircularDependencyDetectorMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, ResolveRequest request)
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.ExecuteOperation(ResolveRequest request)
> at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance) at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
> at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.Resolve[TService](IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
> at MyProject.UI.WPF.App.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e) in F:\Projects\MyProject\UI\MyProject.UI.WPF\App.xaml.cs: Zeile64
> at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
> at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
> at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
> at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
> at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)

### Inner exeption:

> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: "None of the constructors found with 'Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.DefaultConstructorFinder' on type 'MyProject.ViewModel.MainWindowViewModel' can be invoked with the available services and parameters:
> Cannot resolve parameter 'MyProject.Model.Interfaces.IMyProjectData data' of constructor 'Void .ctor(MyProject.Model.Interfaces.IMyProjectData, CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Messaging.IMessenger)'."

### Stack trace inner exception:

> at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(ResolveRequestContext ctxt, Action`1 next) at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.DisposalTrackingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)
> at Autofac.Core.Resolving.Middleware.ActivatorErrorHandlingMiddleware.Execute(ResolveRequestContext context, Action`1 next)

I checked that all three "Installer"-classes are reached and the registration is executed properly.
At the point of the exception I tryed the container: All servicec can be resolved, expected:

> `_container.Resolve<IMyProjectData>()` and

> `_container.Resolve<ISettings>()`
> (this is required as parameter for IMyProjectData.ctor)

Can anybody see why the exception raises? It seems I'm blind for the moment!
Thank you in advance for your response.

Comment: What is the full namespace of ```MyProjectData``` class and ```IMyProjectData``` interface?

Comment: @MikeMozhaev: namespace of 'MyProjectData' is 'MyProject.Model' and namespace of 'IMyProjectData' is 'MyProjectData.Model.Interfaces'

Comment: Is it MyProjectData.Model.Interfaces.IMyProjectData or MyProject.Model.Interfaces.IMyProjectData? The error says:

Cannot resolve parameter '__MyProject__.Model.Interfaces.IMyProjectData data'

Comment: Also, could you please drill down to inner exception(s) to see the deepest one?

Comment: @MikeMozhaev I edited the Exception section of my description an added stack traces. with reference to the naming: all namespaces start with MyProject... , the projects main data class is called MyProjectData (located in namespace MyProject.Model) implementing the interface IMyProjectData (located in MyProject.Model.Interfaces). - BTW: if you are interrested I can upload the complete project to my github page ;-)

Comment: I see `MyProjectData` is declared as partial class. Where is the other part(s) of this class? Are they in the same namespace?

Comment: @MikeMozhaev the other part is autogenerated by ComunityToolkit.MVVM => MyProjectData is derived from ObservableObject

Comment: Then uploading the project to GitHub should help.

Comment: @MikeMozhaev uploaded to github under [Link](https://github.com/KingSB60/FotoRenamer) - MyProject was only a dummy for here ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have 2 instances of FotoRenamer.Model.dll loaded.

If you set a breakpoint on the faulting line and then open `Debug->Windows->Modules` you will see it. It's caused by loading the assemblies with `Assembly.LoadFile()`. The assemblies loaded this way are loaded into different load context (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/best-practices-for-assembly-loading?source=recommendations for details about load contexts).

Since all assemblies are referenced by the main project you don't need to load them. The fix is simple:

```cs
    public static void InstallAutofac(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Installer));
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);

        assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(ViewModel.Installer));
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);

        assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Model.Installer));
        builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(assembly);
    }
```

Comment: this helped! thank you! Did'nt see that ;-(